# Which of the Platform Modules makes app process unique?

Tags: netbeans-platform, netbeans-7.1

In Netbeans Platform application I wanted to turn off all unneeded modules, so I went to `Project Properties > Libraries` and turned off the **platform** module group. After that some warnings appeared about dependencies and I've clicked **Resolve** in the same window.

After that app builds just fine, but when I run it, I get the next error:

```
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/harness/suite.xml:498: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/harness/run.xml:193: The application is already running within the test user directory.
You must shut it down before trying to run it again.
```

I'm 100% sure that no other instance is running, so it probably conflicts with IDE itself.

Do you have any idea what module should be turned on to solve this problem?

Comment: For me, deleting the directory "build/testuserdir" fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've found at last what modules are messing up all the stuff.

It's **NetBeans OSGi Integration** or **NetBeans Equinox Integration** module in *platform* cluster. They both are dependent on each other as well as on **OSGi Specification** module. When they are added back the app runs as intended.

Comment: Be sure and mark this answer as accepted so that others will know that there is a solution.